# PHP equivalent to Python's struct

Tags: php, python, struct

I am trying to port the following Python code to PHP, but I can't find the PHP equivalent to Python's `struct`. (and I specifically need an equivalent to `struct.calcsize()`) Is there any PHP equivalent that I could use?

```
import struct
attr_fmt = ">iii4x"
attr_size = struct.calcsize(self.attr_fmt)
```

#### EDIT:

For those that are not familiar with Python, but are with PHP, from the [`struct` manual page](http://docs.python.org/library/struct.html):

> This module performs conversions between Python values and C structs represented as Python strings. This can be used in handling binary data stored in files or from network connections, among other sources. It uses Format Strings as compact descriptions of the layout of the C structs and the intended conversion to/from Python values.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not familiar with Python's struct, but it looks a bit like PHP's `pack` and `unpack`. I'm not aware of any direct way to determine the size before hand.

Here's an example that I believe is the same as yours:

```
$fmt = 'N3x4'; // three 32-bit big endian integers followed by 4 bytes of padding
$s = pack($fmt, 0, 0, 0); // pack the data into a string
$size = strlen($s);       // find the length of the data
```

In this example, I chose three dummy `0`s to use as the arguments for the three integers.

To unpack the data, it would look like:

```
$fmt = 'N3/x4';
$a = unpack($fmt, $s);
echo $a[0];
```

Comment: Check my question edit, is that what it does? If so, could you provide some reference and/or examples?

Comment: Essentially, yes. `unpack()` takes binary data and converts it into a PHP array. `pack()` takes a series of PHP args and creates a binary string. I don't have time to write out an example right now, but you may want to look at http://us2.php.net/pack for the syntax. But, again, I'm not sure that there's a function to take a format string and directly calculate a size from it.

Comment: I don't need a direct function, achieving the same in a few steps would be fine as well... I've been playing with `pack()` a bit, but I can't seem to get it to do the same...

Comment: I've added an example. I do not know if it produces the same results as the Python version or not.